# Проблема с пулом потоков

Tags: многопоточность, потоки-данных, java

На кластере запускаю несколько одноузловых заданий. Каждое задание, состоит, по сути, из цикла, который решил распараллелить в пределах узла, чтобы сэкономить время. По этому одноузловое задание в своей работе использует все ядра узла.   
Запуск нескольких заданий показал, что они "подвисают". В логе показывает, что проблема следующая:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10079"

(отметил строку, в которой проблема)

Ниже приведен код, который запускает задание. Не соображу в чем может быть проблема. Помогите..

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

...

PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(
            new FileOutputStream("result.txt"));

int processorsNumber = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
ExecutorService executer = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(processorsNumber);

List<Parallel7_Dispatcher_PID_nonDimensional> tasks = new LinkedList<Parallel7_Dispatcher_PID_nonDimensional>();

 // Вот этот цикл и нужно распараллелить   
for ( int i = p_start; i < p_start + n; i++ ){
    for ( int j = i_start; j < i_start + n; j++ ){
        for ( int k = d_start; k < d_end; k++ ){

        double kp = start_kp + (double) step * i;
        double ki = start_ki + (double) step * j;
        double kd = start_kd + (double) step * k;

        tasks.add(new Parallel7_Dispatcher_PID_nonDimensional(kp, ki, kd));
        }
    }
}

List<Future<double[]>> res = executer.invokeAll(tasks);

for ( Future<double[]> future : res ){

    double[] results = future.get(); // Проблема здесь

    synchronized (output) {
        output.println(results[0] + "\t" + results[1]  + "\t" + results[2] + "\t" + results[3]);
    }
}

executer.shutdown();
output.close();
}
```

Comment: 'synchronized (output)' - мне кажется это лишнее

Comment: @jmu, в любом случае, ошибка не из-за этого..

Comment: @Stas0n очевидно что я пытался предотвратить другую ошибку. скорее за все проблема в этом классе :  Parallel7_Dispatcher_PID_nonDimensional

Comment: Спасибо, но уже разобрался с проблемой, которая, кстати, не в этом классе была. И как всегда - по невнимательности.

Answer (score 1):

Исключение [`ExecutionException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutionException.html) при получении результата выполнения из `Future` означает, что сама задача в пуле завершилась с исключением. Так как задача выполнялась в параллельном потоке, который контролирует сам пул, вы не могли отреагировать на исключение сразу же. Поэтому исключение поймал пул потоков и просто запомнил его. А когда вы сделали `Future.get()`, пул потоков обернул исключение в `ExecutionException` и кинул вам. Исходное исключение можно достать с помощью `getCause()`. В данном случае это как раз `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`: где-то внутри задачи `Parallel7_Dispatcher_PID_nonDimensional` вы обратились за пределы массива, указав индекс `10079`. Если вы воспользуетесь, например, `ex.printStackTrace()`, там будет примерно такое:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10079
    at MyClass.main(MyClass.java:50)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10079
    at Parallel7_Dispatcher_PID_nonDimensional.call(Parallel7_Dispatcher_PID_nonDimensional.java:1234)
    at ...
```

Таким образом, посмотрев на caused by, вы можете узнать, в каком классе, каком методе и какой строке кода на самом деле произошло изначальное исключение.

Answer (score 0):

Я насколько понимаю проблема именно здесь double[] results
Т.е. По сути этот массив пока null. А определить его нужно Как то так

```
double[] results = new double[50];
```

Ну с кол-вом нужным вам. А вы сразу пытаетесь в него дынные сувать. 
Такой тип данных Вам скорее всего не подходит. 
Раз нужно динамически изменяемое, то смотрите в сторону ArrayList или хешей.

Comment: Нет, ошибка не в этом, поскольку "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException". ExecutionException - это лишь обертка под это исключение. Вот сейчас вожусь с кодом, пытаясь в чем косяк...